# RDP access to DirectAccess Server via DirectAccess

Tags: windows-server-2008, direct-access

I have just setup a Win2008R2 DirectAccess server (and also a Win2008R2 Active Directory server).

From the Internet I can Remote Desktop login to the AD server, but I cannot RDP into the DirectAccess server. I can PING both servers and get an IPv6 response.

(I can RDP to the DirectAccess server from the internal company network)

DirectAccess is configured to allow full intranet access.

I think I've hit a mental block, the answer will probably be obvious, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try both the internal and the external IP of the directaccess server? Try and connect to IP instead of name just to see if that helps.

Comment: DirectAccess uses IPv6 and NRPT.  When I ping the host it resolves to an IPv6 address (as expected) and I get an ICMP reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the DirectAccess server setup to require NT Network Authentication? That probably can't happen outside of the network. I know it doesn't work for my systems.

Comment: It might be related to the fact that the DirectAccess server is the IPSEC endpoint. I suspect my problem might be related to an IPSEC policy on the DirectAccess server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi im having the same issues finaly got directaccess setup and working but i also want to access the the direct access server via RDP and network shares via directaccess clients.

Not sure who to ask but is it designed to not allow external access?

Answer (score 0):

Can you RDP onto the public IPv4 address of the Direct Access server? I understood they always have to have two public IPv4 addresses